# Convert input String to File Object

Tags: java, string, file, jaxb

I want to convert the input string which is nothing but the xml to JAVA object. I am using JAXB for the same. But my problem is from calling application I am going to receive XML in the form of string. But `jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputXML);` expects a FILE object in the input. So is there is some way I can convert input String into FILE object without manually writing this incoming content into disk.

Following is my method snippet

```
public void xmlToObject(String inputXML){
        try{
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(LineItemsBeanList.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            LineItemsBeanList objreq= (LineItemsBeanList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputXML);
            printLineItems(objreq.getLineItemsBean());
            nba.processLineItems(objreq.getLineItemsBean());
            nba.printFinalSetOfRules();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a File object to solve this problem.

Taken from the [docs for JAXB Unmarshaller](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html):

> Unmarshalling from a StringBuffer using a javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
StringBuffer xmlStr = new StringBuffer( "<?xml version="1.0"?>..." );
Object o = u.unmarshal( new StreamSource( new StringReader( xmlStr.toString() ) ) );
```

In your case you can use a similar method for unmarshalling from a string:

```
LineItemsBeanList objreq = (LineItemsBeanList) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(
    new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML)));
```